# override CSS :after /:befor selector

Tags: css

I have two div's the first one with a zig-zag bottom border and an image should be on both div's, the image always go behind the zig-zag border. i tried the z-index property but it did not work. can someone help with this issue? or is there any another approach to draw the zigzag border ?thanks in advance.

```css
#d-wrapper {
background-color: #950051;
}
#d-wrapper * {

margin:0;
padding:0;}

#d-wrapper div.sep {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 32px 0;
 }
  
#d-wrapper div > * {
  margin: 0 40px;
 }

#d-wrapper .zig-zag-bottom{
  margin: 32px 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #1ba1e2;
    padding: 32px 0;
 }

#d-wrapper p,
#d-wrapper  h1{
    font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:"PT Sans Narrow", "Fjalla One", sans-serif;
    font-weight:900;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #1b90e2, 2px 2px 0 #1b90e2, 3px 3px 0 #1b90e2, 4px 4px 0 #1b90e2, 5px 5px 0 #1b90e2;

 }

#d-wrapper div.sec-dev p,
#d-wrapper  div.sec-dev h1 {
  text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #888, 2px 2px 0 #888, 3px 3px 0 #888, 4px 4px 0 #888, 5px 5px 0 #888;
  color: #fff;
 }

#d-wrapper h1{
   font-size:4em;
 }

#d-wrapper .zig-zag-bottom:after{
  background: 
     linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 16px, #1ba1e2 0), 
     linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 16px, #1ba1e2  0);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: left bottom;
        background-size: 22px 32px;
        content: "";
        display: block;

  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;

      position: relative;
  top:64px;
  left:0px;
 }

#d-wrapper p{
  text-align: center;
 }

p {
  text-align: center;    
}
```

```html
<div id="d-wrapper">
        <div class="zig-zag-bottom">
            <h1>Title 1</h1>

            <p>Content 1</p>
            <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/131677/isolated/preview/5517f3c8facf7ff407aaa7752c00e8a5-paintbrush-tool-by-vexels.png" alt="Smiley face" width="160px" height="180px" style="margin-bottom: -150px;">
        </div>

        <div class="sec-dev">
            <h1>Title 2</h1>
            
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `z-index` to work, the element needs to be non-static.

Along with `z-index` try applying `position: relative` on the image.